# Does anyone know how to modify the document autoformat feature in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, autoformatting, word-2013

I'm trying to automate applying a format to a document in Word. The Autoformat dialog has three options for Document Type: General Document; Letter; Email. I had thought that I could create a template based on the document type, but I can't find much documentation on this feature and a search of the Word folders doesn't turn up anything promising. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

[image: Word Autoformat dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is StackOverflow (=programming) I'm going to assume you're looking for a way to access this via VBA (a macro). The AutoFormat "type" is set using the Document.Kind object, which takes a member of the WdDocumentKind Enum:

```
wdDocumentEmail        2 E-mail format. 
wdDocumentLetter       1 Letter format. 
wdDocumentNotSpecified 0 No format specified.
```

Recording a macro while applying AutoFormat gives code like this:

```
Selection.Document.Kind = wdDocumentLetter
Selection.Range.AutoFormat
```

It's not very clear to me why you'd want to use AutoFormat when setting up a template. Usually, when people take the trouble to use a template they also define a set of styles and a UI for people to use the styles...

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I was hoping to gain more control over the way in which Word interpreted the document being processed - e.g. convert a single line, 14pt Times to Heading 2, convert x to y. I've also been looking at pandoc I think I may have better luck with that. Best /E

Comment: It would help if you put that information in your question... FWIW there never was any official documentation. Many years ago, when it was first introduced I remember there being some guidelines on how to format the plain text so that, say, a heading level would be applied. But never anything as specific as you're thinking about. In Word, a Find/Replace macro would probably be the better approrach for what you describe.